# How to "draw" a coordination bond (dashed bond) in MOLFILE?

Tags: bond, coordination-compounds, organometallic-compounds, cheminformatics

How can we "draw" a coordination bond (dashed bond) in MOLFILE?

I cannot find a bond property or option that would allow me to choose such a thing.

So many drawings of organo-metallic compounds (e.g., metal ion and chelator) contain that.

How come the MOLFILE format doesn't support such a thing?

Comment: Generally, Lewis structures do not support dative bonds (dashed or arrows and the like); V2000 simply might be too old to have this implemented. IUPAC recommends something different for schemes for organometallic compounds, where the lines lose their strict character (and are definitively not Lewis(-like) structures).

Comment: The BIOVIA documentation about CTfiles, [August 2020 edition, pdf file](https://web.archive.org/web/20210219065450/https://discover.3ds.com/sites/default/files/2020-08/biovia_ctfileformats_2020.pdf) documents both v2000 and v3000 format, with *preference* for the v3000 format (p. 1). Chapter 2, p. 11 includes a table «Meaning of the values in the bond block [of v3000 format]» which just follows the atoms and their coordinates, this mentions type `9` with two sub-types about coordination, either for metal complexes, or for Lewis acids/bases.

Answer (score 3):

While currently not functional for me, RDKit's cookbook includes a relevant entry to this, though.  Instead of dashes, the dative bond would be represented by an arrow pointing toward the transition metal, e.g.

[image]

([from RDKit's Cookbook](http://www.rdkit.org/docs/Cookbook.html#organometallics-with-dative-bonds))

in a section called [Organometallics with Dative Bonds](http://www.rdkit.org/docs/Cookbook.html#organometallics-with-dative-bonds).

If you use `.sdf` in the v3000 format,* RDKit may be adjusted to visualize dative bonds as dotted lines, too:

[image]

([Esben Jannik Bjerrum, cheminformania.com](https://www.cheminformania.com/how-to-solve-problems-with-coordinate-bonds-in-rdkit/))

*) The current definition of `.sdf` files by Biovia (August 2020, [link to .pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20210219065450/https://discover.3ds.com/sites/default/files/2020-08/biovia_ctfileformats_2020.pdf)) describes in detail the types of bonds available in the v3000 format to the *bond block* (cf. p. 11).  Type `9` is set for *coordination* with dipolar bonds of either sub-type `COORD` for coordination bonds in metal complexes, or `DATIVE` for bond between Lewis acids and bases. (There might be a concptual overlap here.)  Bond type `10`, by the way, offers two sub-types to handle hydrogen bonds, too.

Comment: So that's not really anything explicit in the MOLFILE, but I suppose we could use the same logic they used: "Process organometallic SMILES by detecting single bonds between metals and replacing with dative bonds." So whenever in the bond table in a MOLFILE I find one of the atoms a metal, I would draw a dashed line instead of a solid line. I have my own MOLFILE renderer so I can do that.

Comment: I noticed that PubChem also uses that convention, and it was easy enough for me to implement. Single bond with any ligand being a metal --> dashed line.

Comment: Alex Clark published a proposal for zero order bonds as an extension to SD files. It’s supported by some software, but I don’t think there’s a list anywhere.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow Just out of curiosity about «I have my own MOLFILE renderer so I can do that», is this program somewhere presented in a publication, mirrored on a repository like GitHub/commercialized? An answer in lines of «No, it is an application working fine for me, not intended for publication» were acceptable, too.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison I just passed a fairly recent documentation of the ctfiles (BIOVIA, August 2020) [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210219065450/https://discover.3ds.com/sites/default/files/2020-08/biovia_ctfileformats_2020.pdf).  Page 11 (or, counting the pages in the pdf, p. 17) describes 10 different bond types (single, double, triple, etc.) without even touching the bond's configuration as either «up», «down», «either», or «none».  Possibly «no bond at all» does not fit level `8`, *any bond order*.

Comment: Just a technicality nitpick: instead of writing "credit" and hiding the link, I find it preferable to actually name the source. That makes it easier to recognise the credit once the link rots away and is easier recognised by most readers. Additionally, it might also be a criterion that allows use of an image; in any case, I find it better to be on the safe side with this.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン With some thought, this is a convincing argument. It is going to be implemented for illustrated answers in future and, when encountered, in those already given (about 0.5k).

Comment: @Buttonwood - The zero bond order proposal is an extension https://doi.org/10.1021/ci200488k and as I said, I don't think there's a list of programs that support ZBO.